# React SideBar Multi Level dropdown recursion

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, sidebar, submenu

I have a code below. I want when the user clicks on the Analytics tab on the sidebar navigation, it will display the submenu on the right side. Can anyone have some ideas to do it?

[image: Dashboard]

route.js

```
import Analytics from 'views/Analytics.jsx';

const dashboardRoutes = [
   {
     path: "/analytics",
    name: "Analytics",
    icon: "pe-7s-graph",
    component: Analytics,
    layout: "/admin",
    dashboardRoutes : 
    [{
       name: "Building",
      component: Buildings
    },
    {
      name: "Group",
      component: Groups
    },
    {
      name: "Rooms",
      component: Rooms
    }
    
]
```

In the Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { NavItem, Nav, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import AdminNavbarLinks from "../Navbars/AdminNavbarLinks.jsx";
import {FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

import logo from "assets/img/instahubIcon.png";
import List from 'material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from 'material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from 'material-ui/core/ListItemText'

class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: window.innerWidth
    };
  }
  activeRoute(routeName) {
    return this.props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1 ? "active" : "";
  }
  updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
  }
   render() {
    const sidebarBackground = {
      backgroundImage: "url(" + this.props.image + ")"
    };
    return (
      <div
        id="sidebar"
        className="sidebar"
        data-color={this.props.color}
        data-image={this.props.image}
      >
          {this.props.hasImage ? (
            <div className="sidebar-background" style={sidebarBackground} />
          ) : (
            null
          )}
        <div className="logo">
          <a
            href="https://www.creative-tim.com?ref=lbd-sidebar"
            className="simple-text logo-mini"
          >
            <div className="logo-img">
              <img src={logo} alt="logo_image" />
            </div>
          </a>
         
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul className="nav">
            {this.state.width <= 991 ? <AdminNavbarLinks /> : null}
            {this.props.routes.map((prop, key) => {
              if (prop.invisible) return null;
              if (!prop.redirect)
                return (
                  <li
                    className={
                      prop.upgrade
                        ? "active active-pro"
                        : this.activeRoute(prop.layout + prop.path)
                    }
                    key={key}
                  >
                    <NavLink
                      to={prop.layout + prop.path}
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                      <i className={prop.icon} />
                      <p>{prop.name}</p>
                    </NavLink>
                    
                  </li>
                 
                );
                
              return null;
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Can anyone have a look at my code above and give me some recommendations? Thanks a lot for your help